# RBAC - Access to kubernetes API

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus, prometheus-operator

In the below manifest yaml:

```
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: ClusterRole
metadata:
  name: prometheus-operator
rules:
- apiGroups: [apiextensions.k8s.io]
  resources: [customresourcedefinitions]
  verbs: ['*']
- apiGroups: [monitoring.coreos.com]
  resources: 
  - alertmanagers
  - prometheuses
  - prometheuses/finalizers
  - alertmanagers/finalizers
  - servicemonitors
  - prometheusrules
  verbs: ['*']
```

---

What does `rules` with `apiGroups` signify?

Answer (score 4):

In Kubernetes resources can be either `grouped resources` or `individual resources` .

Example :

```
kubectl api-resources  | grep 'crds\|pods\|NAME'
NAME                              SHORTNAMES   APIVERSION                             NAMESPACED   KIND
pods                              po           v1                                     true         Pod
customresourcedefinitions         crd,crds     apiextensions.k8s.io/v1                false        CustomResourceDefinition
```

In above output , for `pods` `apiVersion` is displayed as `v1` so it is an individual resource . where as for `customresourcedefinitions`  `apiVersion` is displayed as `apiextensions.k8s.io/v1` which indicates that it is a grouped resource under the group `apiextensions.k8s.io`.

When we are defining RBAC rules (roles/clusreroles) for grouped resources we need to mention `apiGroups` along with `resources`.